# What is the correct IPv6 setting for Gstreamer UDPSINK Clients?

Tags: gstreamer

I have a problem with the Gstreamer UDPSINK clients setting for IPv6, but I have successfully worked with IPv4 such as `clients="192.168.10.10:9001,192.168.10.11:9002"`, I have tried to set clients for IPv6 such as `clients="[1234:5678:9ABC:DEF0:1234:5678:9ABC:DEF0]:9001"` without being successful.

Can anyone help to guide me with a correct setting for IPv6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now setting the clients property with ipv6 addresses is somewhat bugged, the compilator treats the first colon symbol as a divider between host and port.

If you want to send data to a single client you should use "host" and "port" properties.

If you want to send data to multiple clients and add clients dynamically then you need to use signals like this:

```
GstElement *your_udpsink_ref = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(your_pipeline), "your_udpsink_name");
g_signal_emit_by_name(your_udpsink_ref, "add", "1234:5678:9ABC:DEF0:1234:5678:9ABC:DEF0", 9001, NULL);
g_object_unref(your_udpsink_ref);
```

Just be sure your pipeline was already running in the playing state (ready is probably fine too) before you emit a signal.